# Iteration on Angular template

Tags: arrays, json, angular, loops, view

I've been working on a Angular project for a few weeks now, and I'm starting to process data to the view.

However, I'm starting to work with iterations, taken from a big JSON, which I've tried to iterate over but I cannot get it right.

I have this **JSON**:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "App Komputer",
    "description": "Website dedicated to computer related products",
    "accessCode": "5128",
    "createdAt": "2022-01-13T21:19:11.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-01-13T21:19:16.000Z",
    "sprints": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Sprint 1",
        "releaseDate": "2022-01-20T21:37:13.000Z",
        "description": "Specs up to 01/22/2022",
        "createdAt": "2022-01-13T21:37:58.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-12-13T01:46:36.000Z",
        "projectId": 1,
        "specifications": [{
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Add product button",
            "description": "New product button HTML",
            "duration": 10,
            "status": 1,
            "createdAt": "2021-12-23T01:46:36.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-12-23T01:46:36.000Z",
            "sprintId": 1
        }]
    }]
}
```

And I'm trying to iterate it so be shown like this:

```
<div>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  <span>Access Code: {{ access_code }}</span>
    -- foreach sprints as sprint --
    <div>{{ sprint.title }}</div>
    -- foreach specifications as specification --
    <div>{{ specification.title }}</div>
    <span>{{ specification.description}}</span>
</div>
```

This is my function, from where I get the data:

```
getProject(id: string): void {
    this.projectService.get(id)
      .subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          this.currentProject = data; // currentProject is the JSON
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: (e) => console.error(e)
      });
  }
```

Can someone help me to accomplish the desired result in my HTML view? How can I iterate through the JSON data?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [*ngFor directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) to iterate over an array and display item data.

lets assume that the variable `data` has your json data. In this case this is how your HTML template would look like.

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<span>Access Code: {{ data?.access_code }}</span>
<div *ngFor="let sprint of data.sprints">
        <div>{{ sprint.title }}</div>
        <div *ngFor="let specification of sprint.specifications">
            <div>{{ specification.title }}</div>
            <span>{{ specification.description }}</span>
        </div>
 </div>
```